# Low-latency audio streaming in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio-streaming

Suppose there is a live WAV stream that can be reached at a certain URL, and we need to stream it with as little latency as possible. Using HTML5 `<audio>` for this task is a no-go, because browsers attempt to pre-buffer several seconds of the stream, and the latency goes up accordingly. That's the reason behind using Flash for this task. However, due to my inexperience with this technology, I only managed to get occasional clicks and white noise. What's wrong in the code below? Thanks.

```
var soundBuffer: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var soundStream: URLStream = new URLStream();
soundStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, readSound);
soundStream.load(new URLRequest(WAV_FILE_URL));
var sound = new Sound();
sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA,playSound);
sound.play();

function readSound(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    soundStream.readBytes(soundBuffer, 0, soundStream.bytesAvailable);
}


function playSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    /* The docs say that if we send too few samples,
      Sound will consider it an EOF */
    var samples:int = (soundBuffer.length - soundBuffer.position) / 4
    var toadd:int = 4096 - samples;
    try {
      for (var c: int=0; c < samples; c++) {
        var n:Number = soundBuffer.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(n);
        event.data.writeFloat(n);
      }
    } catch(e:Error) {
        ExternalInterface.call("errorReport", e.message);
    }
    for (var d: int = 0; d < toadd; d++) {
        event.data.writeFloat(0);
        event.data.writeFloat(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay; any advice on the core problem?

Comment: Yup, The sound object can only play MP3s

Comment: Not quite. The Adobe live docs even contain an example of playing a dynamically generated sine wave using exactly this method (except the loading par, of course). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html

Comment: Just because you can generate sound via bitmap writing doesn't mean you can decode an audio file. The two are not connected. A WAV will use a codex that the sound object doesn't understand.

Comment: How low of latency is required?  100ms?  1 second?  5 seconds?

Comment: We're targeting 500ms, but I think that latency up to 1sec should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like The_asMan pointed out, playing a wav file is not that easy.  See [as3wavsound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/) for an example.

If your goal is low latency, the best option would be to convert to MP3, so you can use just [use a SoundLoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d22.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, I still get pretty high latency (>4 seconds) despite setting the bufferTime of SoundLoaderContext and globally at SoundMixer to 50ms. Any advice?

Comment: You can try loading the entire file first with `URLLoader`, then using `Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray`.  That should tell you if something about the file or Flash is causing latency.  If not, then it must be something with the network.